# how to find service_name that I deleted in oracle11g

Tags: oracle11g

I changed and saved service_name in tnsnames.ora. Now I cannot connect to oracle and remember also. Can anyone tell me how I find service_name

Answer (score 0):

If you followed installation recommendations than the service_name should be the same as the SID.